# [: <filename>: unexpected error in shell programming

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have created a script which creates two files and reverses their contents if both the files are different. I cant understand how to resolve this error :

> [: my-filename: unexpected error in shell programming

Code:

```
echo "Enter first filename :"
read file1
echo "Enter second filename:"
read file2
echo "Enter content of file 1 : "
gedit $file1
echo "Enter content of file 2 : "
gedit $file2

check=" " 

x=` cmp $file1 $file2 `
if [ $x -eq $check ]
then
echo "Both files are same"
rm $file2
echo "Redundant file removed!!!"
else
echo "They are different"
fi

tac $file1 | cat > temp1
rev temp1 | cat > temp11 
tac $file2 | cat > temp2
rev temp2 | cat > temp22
mv temp11 $file1
mv temp22 $file2

echo "Content of both the files reversed"
```

Comment: Which line of code is causing the error?

Comment: My guess is this: `if [ $x -eq $check ]` should probably be rewritten as `if [ "$x" == "$check" ]` for a start.

Comment: When asking a question like this you need to post the smallest fragment of code that displays the problem.  That means (since your problem is almost certainly in your `if`) skipping all the "enter content" stuff, and the `tac` stuff (whatever that is).  You should be able to produce a four- or five-line example which reproduces what's going wrong.  The payoff (beyond making it much likelier that people will help you) is that you quite often discover the fix for yourself by this route.

Comment: @NormanGray: tac is the reverse of cat, and it does the reverse of cat.  It catenates a file bottom to top.

Comment: You should learn how to interpret the output of `sh -x your-script`.  If you remove `$file2`, the `tac` and `rev` operations on it are not going to work well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cmp` directly from the `if` statement

```sh
if cmp -s $file1 $file2
then
  echo "Both files are same"
  rm $file2
  echo "Redundant file removed!!!"
else
  echo "They are different"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give which shell you are using.

But I think `if [ $x -eq $check ]` cause the problem. Your shell interpret the file name which include the '-' as a switch. you can either rename my-filename to myfilename or double quote the $x:

```
if [ "$x" -eq "$check" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

In bash, the logical operators -eq -ne  -gt -lt -ge -le are specific for numeric arguments. For comparing string you can simply use

```
if [ $x = $check ]; then
 # do whatever
fi
```